# I am invisible in Skyrim without any active effects

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am invisible in Skyrim without having cast spells or drank potions. I have pressed 'camera on right' toggle on my controller, and nothing changes. I allowed someone to cast a spell on me at the College and have been invisible since. The game is operating normally aside from that aspect. I'm assuming I'm visible to other characters in the game. It's driving me absolutely bonkers.

I don't have the Dragonborn or Dawnguard DLC installed, so I know it's not related to those. I have no mods installed. I only have about four other old saves, and one is from when I was level six with the character in question. I am now almost level 30. The others are from a different character.

Is there any possible help or advice at all, aside from either starting over or just dealing with it?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that u are talking about the quest "Breylna Practice".
This is common and happens to me almost every time i have done the quest. The only way i know to fix it is to use the "Become Ethereal" shout. When it wears off you should be visible again.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by using Solution 4 here:
https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/872861-tutorial-removing-unwanted-magic-effects-from-the-player/

Comment: Please post the solution here as well, not just a link.